# Is there an equivalent to LambdaEntryPoint for Azure Functions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, aws-lambda, azure-functions

On AWS, it's possible to configure an API Gateway to point at a single Lambda, which can then expose a whole AspDotNetCore application, with many controllers and methods. This is known as a [`LambdaEntryPoint`](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/blob/master/Libraries/src/Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer/README.md#lambda-entry-point).

I've been asked to port over a project that utilises this approach and I'm wondering whether there's an equivalent for Azure Functions?

I can see how I might implement it myself, but it seems clunky and obtuse. For instance, I could setup a single HTTP triggered gateway with [customised routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=in-process%2Cfunctionsv2&pivots=programming-language-csharp#customize-the-http-endpoint) with the controller and method as parameters, which I could then feed into a big ol' `switch` statement and call the appropriate method. I mean, it'll get the job done, but its a lot of boilerplate and won't be fun to maintain.

Is there some middleware I can use to make a single Azure Function run an entire AspDotNetCore-based API?

---

**UPDATE:** To address the comment from Thiago Custodio, I'm trying to run this as a Functions App to keep costs down. The usage will be very "bursty" and the app will spend 75% of the time doing nothing. Having a sufficiently capable App Service to handle the 25% will be too expensive.

On AWS, `LambdaEntryPoint` effectively allows one to stick a whole AspDotNetCore application inside a single Lambda. This is a great way to expose an API cheaply and with very elastic scaling in response to demand.

I can see a couple of ways of doing something similar with Azure Functions:

1. Create an HTTP-triggered function for each API method I want to expose.
2. As described above, I could create a single HTTP-triggered entry function, which would then despatch to the correct method based on URL parameters.

Comment: can you add more context what you're trying to do? You can use API Management and just call directly the Aspnet core app. Why do you need the function? Which job will it do?

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio Have added more details to the question as an edit. Thanks!

Comment: I never did such a thing. And as far as I know, there's no 'LambdaEntryPoint' equivalent on Azure Functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the >6 months since I posted this, I feel I've done enough research to confidently say that there is no equivalent to `LambdaEntryPoint` on Azure.

I may start an open source project, as this feels like it would be simple enough to achieve.